# Scheme Error: execute: unbound symbol: "error"

Tags: scheme

I am learning Scheme language in school and trying to use `error` function to handle corner cases. When I try [this code from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938887/scheme-getting-error-is-not-a-function), I got an 
error `Error: execute: unbound symbol: "error" [in?]` instead of printing out the error message.

This is the example code from the link above:

```
(define in? 
  (lambda (el lst)
    (if (or (null? lst) (pair? lst))
        (if (null? lst) 
            #f
            (if (equal? (car lst) el )
                #t
                (in? el (cdr lst))))
        (error "ERROR"))))
```

The input and output should be like:

```
(in? 1 '(2 5 3))
=> #f
(in? 3 '(2 5 3))
=> #t
(in? 1 5)
=> ERROR
```

However, I get:

```
(in? 1 5)
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "error" [in?]
```

I am using repl.it online compiler to compile the Scheme code.
Anyone know why is the error function not definded? Do I suppose to define my own error function? If so, could anyone give me a simple example to show the basic style of writing an error function? I read the reference from [MIT Scheme Error System](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2003/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_17.html) but I feel lost.

Comment: What Scheme implementation are you using?

Comment: @Barmar, I updated the question with the example of Scheme code, is that what you were asking? I am not sure the `implementation` you mean as I am new to Scheme

Comment: [e.g.](https://tio.run/##dZDBDoIwEETvfMUGD2wPHpBw5uTZhD@odIlNSsUWYvTn69ImBDT2sGln3qST9d2NBjryfIeAinptCbRtIANAI4erkoBkwPhJsMSi7gHvDtDOxjRRBxyldumeoBXcQKuxnEO/e0aWHrNkGDvpUoK/FTssJqcfCZe@DGOnUlJsa5BzXLdYmPzctpc2j36GSvvRyFeKl1DgCWqo2IMMLT0Nb0J8UdWG@guVUAsRwgc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the Scheme standard goes there is no procedure or special form called `error`. I've tried it in MIT Scheme and sure enough it is defined and when used signals an error but in repl.it the Scheme implementation is called [BiwaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/) and it isn't compatible with MIT Scheme lock in.

BiwaScheme [doesn't seem to fully support any Scheme standard](http://www.biwascheme.org/doc/conformance.html) so I would not suggest you use it (yet).

I strongly suggest you use a compatible Scheme implementation to one of the current standards when learning Scheme.