# Using sect and slots in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to learn the beginnings of FP, with the help of "Algorithms for Functional Programming". At chapter 2 the writer introduces the `sect` and `<>` keywords. One of the procedures in the book would be:

```
(define add1 (sect + <> 1))
```

I used [Repl.it](http://repl.it) to compute the procedure. But sadly enough, it throws following error:

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "<>" []
```

Then I tried Racket, because I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532257/2049986) here Repl.it uses BiwaScheme which doesn't fully support any Scheme standard. But then I got another error:

```
sect: undefined;
cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

So am I doing something wrong? Or is there another editor / IDE that I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong, both `sect` and `<>` are not Scheme keywords. In the preface it is mentioned the author uses the `(afp primitives)` library for primitive procedures and syntax extensions. By using this library you get a bunch of extra procedures at your disposel.

You can download it [here](https://unity.homelinux.net/afp/code/afp/primitives.sld).

Answer (score 1):

Racket comes with an [`add1`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._add1%29%29) function; no need to define your own.

And it supports [SRFI-26](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) `cut`, which is what that `sect` looks to be by another, more common name:

```lisp
> (require srfi/26)
> ((cut + 1 <>) 2)
3
```